# html difference between equal sign and colon

Tags: html

What is the difference between using = and : when assigning a value in an attribute?
For example:

```
<p style="width=100px, height:1000px"></p>
```

Does anyone have a reliable source that tells the difference between the 2 and their appropriate usage?

Comment: do you mean an = for html element attribute assignment and a semicolon for css property assignment?

Comment: `style="width=100px"` is invalid

Comment: ah my bad, I didn't realize that! thanks for the quick respond. I think I should delete this question as it is too simple.

Comment: The question is a simple one, but people often get confused with issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is used to assign values to attributes in HTML elements. `:` is used to assign values to css based properties.

Example

HTML

```
<p id="p1" height="100px">
```

CSS

```
body{
background-color:red;
}
```

In your example `<p style="width=100px..."` is wrong , you given value to style attribute with `=` but the css properties in that style attribute get values using `:` only. Also you cannot separate css properties with `,` , you have to use `;` to separate them. Correct version would be

```
<p style="width:100px; height:1000px"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `p` is the html element for a paragraph it has an attribute `style` which is used to assign inline **CSS**. With CSS you can assign values to css-properties with

```
propertie : value;
```

so it is similar to a reference to a css file containing:

```
p{
    width: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you **width=100px** inside the style attribute is invalid.

Second thing, your forgot the **semicolon ;** at the end of each property.

Last thing I don't think there is a reliable source that tells the difference between the 2 and their appropriate usage because they are not related.

As the previous answers said, **the equal sign =** is used to assign a value to an **HTML attribute** while the **colon sign :** is used to assign a value to a style property.

**PS:** Your paragraph element should look like this:

```
<p style="width:100px; height:1000px;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

An equals sign “=” is the only valid separator between an attribute name and an attribute value in HTML, though any number of whitespace may appear around it (with no significance). The authoritative reference for this is whichever HTML specification (or draft) you regard as most authoritative. For HTML 4.01, it’s a bit tricky, since HTML 4.01 is nominally based on SGML and normatively cites it, so the SGML standard, ISO 8879 (not available online), would be authoritative. For HTML5 LC, which is by many regarded as the de facto standard, the definition, for HTML syntax, is in clause 8.1.2.3 [Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0).

The syntax of content of a `style` attribute is completely external to HTML. It is in practice a matter of CSS, and in CSS, you don’t set attributes, you set properties. In CSS declarations, a colon “:”, with optional whitespace around it, is *the* separator between a property name and a value. All CSS specifications agree on this. Thus, the style sheet `width=100px, height:1000px` has an invalid declaration `width=100px`, which is ignored. The declaration `height:1000px` is valid as such, but since it has not been properly separated from the preceding declaration with a semicolon “;”. Due to CSS error processing rules, the entire style sheet is ignored.